# 3DS Max 2015 - Boolean Two Objects

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax, autodesk, 3ds

I am using 3DS Max 2015

I have two objects that are overlapping / intersecting. They are mirror images of each other of the exact same size and aligned on the exact same horizontal plane.

I would like to crop off the two extruding ends of the intersecting objects. I have tried all of the boolean and pro-boolean operations and none of them seem to apply to my situation.

Here is an example diagram

```
       |
       o
       |
       |
-+-----+----o--
       |
       |
       +
       |
```

I would like to keep the object ends that have a + symbol, and truncate off the ends with the o symbol. My two objects are multi-curved objects so doing it by hand would be difficult.

What operation would I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create two instances of objects. 
On one leave the part the intersection of two meshes.
On the other one leave the parts that do not overlap. it will have gap in the middle, so You can easily select and delete unwanted edges.

Thic two meshes combined would give You resuld You want to have. But I would not recommend using booleans. Try finding another way with poly modeling. Maybe some selection options from ribbon will be helpful?  It all depends on this meshes, so it's hard to point at exact tool without seeing it.